# SQL result keep repeating

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select name of the location and water condition ID using my code below :

```
SELECT location.loc_name, watercondition.id 
FROM `location`, `watercondition` 
WHERE location.loc_id & watercondition.id = 'LO001'
```

But the result print :

```
 A | LO001 
 A | LO002
 A | LO003
 B | LO001
 B | LO001 
 B | LO002
 C | LO003
```

How to fix it? I want the result like this :

```
A | LO001 
B | LO002
C | LO003
```

Comment: Btw, this `WHERE location.loc_id & watercondition.id = 'LO001'` is technically incorrect for a few reasons. Checking for errors on that would have signaled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being you did not specify a `join` condition for the 2 tables involved. This would result in a cross join, meaning each row in one table would be joined with all the rows in the other.

So you should `join` the tables to get the desired result.

```
SELECT l.loc_name, w.id 
FROM `location` l
JOIN `watercondition` w ON l.loc_id = w.id --change this condition to be appropriate
WHERE l.loc_id= 'LO001'
```

Comment: I'm tending to believe this is the solution / better answer. I may be off on mine but it's a "wiki".

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki. I've **nothing** to gain from this.

Use

```
GROUP BY column
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Additionally, read up on DISTINCT

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

You also have a syntax error in

```
WHERE location.loc_id & watercondition.id
```

Technically, you forgot a `&` or could just have used `AND`.

Consult Logical Operators:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Yet that doesn't make any sense.

Something like:

```
WHERE location.loc_id = 'LO001' && watercondition.id = 'LO001'
```

Comment: I may end up deleting this. However, this is a community wiki post, so anyone can make corrections. Btw, there is no rep points gained when posting as such, so feel free to edit.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT location.loc_name, watercondition.id 
FROM `location`, `watercondition` 
WHERE location.loc_id & watercondition.id = 'LO001'
GROUP BY column
```